# Существует ли StringBuilder в Python?

Tags: python-3.x, строки

Существует ли StringBuilder в Python, подходящий для вывода полей объекта класса ?

Comment: Зачем StringBuilder в Python? Это же не Java.

Comment: Что значит "подходящий для вывода полей объекта класса"?

Comment: Это значит подходящий для того чтобы вывести все поля объекта в виде строки

Comment: мне кажется Вам нужно разобраться в том, что именно Вы хотите и сформулировать свой вопрос, не основываясь на собственных умозаключениях, а на исходной, решаемой Вами задаче. Когда люди увидят какую именно задачу Вам нужно будет решить, им будет проще Вам помочь. Сейчас же непонятно что Вы хотите и зачем это Вам нужно.

Comment: @КириллКондратюк, в 90% случаев достаточно использовать обычный `str`. Он вам не подходит?

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу на первую часть вопроса:

> Существует ли StringBuilder в Python

Нет. Но у вас есть пара вариантов:

1. Создать список (или любой итерируемый объект) строк, которые нужно объединить, и затем соединить их методом `join`: `''.join(parts)`. Добавление в список и `join` работают быстро, поэтому вы фактически получаете аналог `StringBuilder.append`. Это классический способ слить большое число строк.
2. Использовать [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) вместе с любыми способами записи в файл.